# in loopback nodejs how can I use OR AND condition in where clause right now I'm using this but it shows mi data from the table

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

```
   {
      or: [
        { and: [{ cash: 'NEW' }] },
        {editGoalStatus: 'PROCESSING'},
        {editGoalStatus: 'NEW'},
          a]
    }
```

I want record like editGoalStatus should be `PROCESSING` or `NEW` and cash must be `NEW`

Comment: Give more details about your code; what are you trying to achieve ? What are you using to create the query ?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve fetch record from table where editGoalStatus is PROCESSING or NEW  and cash column value must  NEW only those record I want but right now it selects all record

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html) the filter should be something like

```
{
    and: [
        { cash: 'NEW' },
        {editGoalStatus: 'PROCESSING'},
        {editGoalStatus: 'NEW'}
    ]
}
```

So assuming that you wrote the

Answer (score 0):

> I want record like editGoalStatus should be `PROCESSING` or `NEW` and cash
>   must be `NEW`

```
{
    and: [
        { cash: 'NEW' },
        { editGoalStatus: { inq: ['PROCESSING', 'NEW'] } }
    ]
}
```

Hope this might be a hint.

Cheers!